# How to prompt user for file name?

Tags: java, excel, apache

export content to an xls file using java with save dialog:
 - Where should I ask for a file name during save?
I prefer to ask what to name the file when it is saved.

```
public static void main(String args[]) 
{
 SaveToExcel exp = new SaveToExcel();
     exp.writePropertiesIntoExcel("D:\\ExcelFile.xls");      
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [JFileChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) if you want to let the users choose where to save the file.

```
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION);

    chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
    int returnVal = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
    if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
    File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    String a = f.getAbsolutePath();
    SaveToExcel exp = new SaveToExcel();
    exp.writePropertiesIntoExcel(a);
}
```

A simple code you can use in your method, this gets the path you want to save your file in.

Comment: Have I any problem to imitate this in POI, because i try it and result is not good

Comment: Your question says that you know how to generate a XLS file, but your are having problems saving it ... "Where should I ask for a file name during save? I prefer to ask what to name the file when it is saved" My answer is for this question of yours.

Comment: Thank you. For now everything is great.

Comment: And if is possible I want this dialog to ask the user to save as "xls" file (excel document) by default  and if I could change the default saving directory